# Add quotation marks (") to end of specific lines using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text of 120k similar to the one below and to I want to add " (quotation marks) at the end of the lines which are finishing in `lr:`. Could you please tell me how to do it using sed or awk?

```
HSS-ServiceProfile=consumer_mmtel_d426s6
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42601:sip\\:d426s6mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;call=orig;lr:
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42603:sip\\:d426s6mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;call=orig;lr:
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42605:sip\\:d426s6mtastermrg.routingcore.imsw..it;call=term;lr:
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42607:sip\\:d426s6mtastermnr.routingcore.imsw..it;call=term;lr:
    hss-DefaultApplicationServer="sip:d426s6mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;lr"
    hss-DefaultASHandling="SESSION_CONTINUED"
    hss-DsaiCapability=false
```

commit -s
up

```
HSS-ServiceProfile=Pk3_mmtel_d426s1
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42601:sip\\:d426s1mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;call=orig;lr:SESSION_CONTINUED"
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42603:sip\\:d426s1mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;call=orig;lr:SESSION_TERMINATED"
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42605:sip\\:d426s1mtastermrg.routingcore.imsw..it;call=term;lr:SESSION_TERMINATED"
    hss-Trigger2ApplicationServers="42607:sip\\:d426s1mtastermnr.routingcore.imsw..it;call=term;lr:SESSION_TERMINATED"
    hss-DefaultApplicationServer="sip:d426s1mtasorig.routingcore.imsw..it;lr"
    hss-DefaultASHandling="SESSION_TERMINATED"
    hss-DsaiCapability=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell sed to replace `lr:` at the end of a line with itself plus double quotes:

```
sed -e 's/lr:$/&"/'
#            ^ ^
#            | |
#      End of  |
#       line   The whole
#              matching part
```